# Advanced css sprite menu w/ background-position placement conundrum

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently trying to create a vertical css-sprite menu inside a 150wx300h div using background-positioning.

```
{http://removed/test1/images}
```

To better understand heres an example of a 450x100 vertical css-sprite menu.
    {http://removed/test1/index}

The main problem i'm currently having is positioning a 750x100 vertical image in the div. After refreshing the sidemen.png disappears, but by hovering the mouse over it you can see the display blocks(links) there.
    {http://removedtest2/index}

Since the css menu displays in blocks of 50 height pixels the menu should fit snuggly..300px/6 = 50px..also trying to figure out how to remove the space above the #menu2(css ul) inside the 150wx300h div,but i doubt that is the culprit because i tried increasing the rightMENU height to 900px.

If it's any help whatsoever ..The css horizontal menu tutorial gone vertical..
     http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/animated-menus-using-jquery/

```
#rightMENU{width:150px;height:300px;margin-left:700px;position:absolute;}  

ul#menu2 {

width:100%;
height:50px;

list-style:none;


}

ul#menu2 li {
float:right;
list-style-type: none;


}
ul#menu2 li a {
background:url(images/sidemen.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
display:block;
height:50px;
position:relative;

}
 ul#menu2 li a.zombiemod {
width:150px;
}
ul#menu2 li a.deathmatch {
width:150px;
background-position:-150px 0px;
}

ul#menu2 li a.deathrun {
width:150px;
background-position:-300px 0px;
}
ul#menu2 li a.s1 {
width:150px;
background-position:-450px 0px;
}
ul#menu2 li a.s2 {
width:150px;
background-position:-600px 0px;
}
ul#menu2 li a.s3 {
width:150px;
background-position:-750px 0px;
}



ul#menu2 li a span {
background:url(images/sidemen.png) no-repeat scroll bottom left;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;


}

ul#menu2 li a.zombiemod span {
background-position:0px -50px;
}
ul#menu2 li a.deathmatch span {
background-position:-150px -50px;
}

ul#menu2 li a.deathrun span {
background-position:-300px -50px;
}

ul#menu2 li a.s1 span {
background-position:-450px -50px;
}

ul#menu2 li a.s2 span {
background-position:-600px -50px;
}

ul#menu2 li a.s3 span {
background-position:-750px -50px;
}



HTML

 <div id="rightMENU">
                 <ul id="menu2">
<li><a href="#" class="zombiemod"><span></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="deathmatch"><span></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="deathrun"><span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="s1"><span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="s2"><span></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="s3"><span></span></a></li>
 </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your filename.

Just remove the space in `sidemen .png`  before the `.png` and it should work fine.

Comment: A tip for next time. You should use browsers developer tools to debug things like that. I right-clicked your sidebar and clicked inspect element and it was immediately apparent what the problem was as their were seven 404 errors saying that sidemen.png could not be found.

Comment: 6 hours i spent trying to debug it. What a find!, but anywho..thanks.